# Updating an ng-repeat property in one controller based on the ng-repeat property of another controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two separate Angular controllers, one in the main content area (`homeCtrl`) showing a list of events, and one in the sidebar (`sidebarCtrl`) showing a list of tags for events.

```
// homeCtrl.js
$scope.events = [{
  name: "Example Event Name",
  tags: [
    {  
       "id":7,
       "name":"Imaginon",
       "following": "false"
    },
  ]
}];
```

In the sidebar controller I have a collection of the most frequently used tags:

```
// sidebarCtrl.js
$scope.tags = [  
  {  
     "id":17,
     "name":"MintMuseum",
     "following": "true"
  },
  {  
     "id":7,
     "name":"Imaginon",
     "following": "false"
  }];
```

I would like it so that if the user starts following a tag in the sidebar, the tag gets highlighted in both the sidebar and in the home feed. If we were *just* trying to highlight it in the sidebar that would be easy enough:

```
// sidebar.html
<div ng-repeat="tag in tags"> 
  <li ng-class="{highlighted: tag.following}" ng-click="followTag(tag)">{{ tag.name }}
</div>
```

But I don't know how to then highlight all instances of that tag color in the home feed. It would be super easy in jQuery by just giving each instance of tag in the document a class of `tag_17` (or whatever ID that tag happened to be) but it'd be nice to avoid jQuery and use Angular's data binding paradigm if possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to create a service to hold data between controllers. Or https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: You'd also need $watch to watch for the values if they change.

Comment: But how can I associate the tags between these two controllers, given that their overall data types are so different (i.e. the tags inside the events on the `homeCtrl.js` are nested objects of their parent event objects?) Is it even possible / feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a service, called highlightService for instance:

```
myModule.factory('highlightService', function() {

   var highlighted = [];

   var toggleHighlight = function(tag) {
      var index = highlighted.indexOf(tag);
      if(index > -1) {
         highlighted.splice(index, 1);
      }
      else{
         highlighted.push(tag);
      }
   }

    return {
        highlighted: highlighted,
        highlight: highlight
    }
});
```

Inject the service into your controller, then assign a local scope variable to it:

```
$scope.highlightService = highlightService;
```

Then in your html:

```
<div ng-repeat="tags in highlightService.highlighted">
   <div ng-click="highlightService.highlight(tag)></div>
</div>
```

Both controllers will contain a reference to the same object, so they will see each other's changes on that object during angular's $digest cycle, and everything will be updated appropriately.

Alternatively you could make a filter available in the service, repeat over a local array of tags with the filter from the provided service.

EDIT: Here is an example of how to do that:

```
myApp.controller('highlightService', [function() {
    var highlightedIDs = [];

    var isHighlighted = function(tag) {
        if(var index = highlightedIDs.indexOf(tag.id) > -1) {
            return index;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    var highlight = function(tag) {
        var index = isHighlighted(tag.id);
        if(index) {
            highlightedIDs.splice(index, 1);
        }
        else {
            highlightedIDs.push(tag.id);
        }
    }

    return {
        isHighlighted: isHighlighted,
        highlight: hilight
    }
}]).filter('highlighted', ['highlightService', function(highlightService) {
    return function(input) {
        if(highlightService.isHighlighted(input) {
            return input;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Use both the service and filter in your HTML as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tahsis. I can see how this would populate our factory with stuff when tags are clicked in the sidebar. 

What I don't see, however, is how the homeCtrl would be aware of this. In my code above, the two controllers' data are coming from two separate database queries and thus are not the same Javascript objects. Their similarity is in terms of == but not in terms of ===.

Comment: You can make an array that keeps track of the IDs of highlighted tags and then make a filter or a function call with the ng-repeat.

Comment: I have edited my answer to have a filter and service that return the same tag after matching it with an array of ids.

Comment: Wow. I've only been using Angular for a few months but I'm realizing how powerful it is. Thanks for your help @Tahsis.